# Iterate through attribute values with minidom

Tags: python, python-3.x, minidom

I have some xml that looks like this:

```
<topic>
    <restrictions>
        <restriction id="US"/>
        <restriction id="CA"/>
        <restriction id="EU"/>
    </restrictions>
</topic>
<topic>
    <restrictions>
        <restriction id="JP"/>
        <restriction id="AU"/>
        <restriction id="EU"/>
        <restriction id="US"/>
    </restrictions>
</topic>
```

And different iterations with the same pattern. I'm already using minidom in my script to do some other things with the xml. For the example above I need to get as result the following:

```
[['US','CA','EU'],['JP','AU','EU','US']]
```

I have tried different iterations with the incorrect result. This is my code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse(path_to_file)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('restrictions')
itemlist2 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('restriction')


restrictions=[]

for x in itemlist:
    res=[]
    for s in itemlist2:
        res.append(s.attributes['id'].value)

    restrictions.append(res)

print(restrictions)
```

Can you please help me to get the iteration correctly? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Just realized something else might happen that I need to account for just in case. It can also happen that a topic element does not have a  element at all, and when that happens, the value appended to the list should be just 0. What is an easy way to make that condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns all elements with the corresponding tag name. So `itemlist2` contains all `restriction` notes in the XML. In your code, it will add all these nodes `['US','CA','EU','JP','AU','EU','US']` for each `restrictions` node. So you should try to get `restriction` nodes for each `restrictions` node separately in the loop.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse(path_to_file)
restrictions=[]
topic_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('topic')
for topic_node in topic_nodes:
  restrictions_nodes = topic_node.getElementsByTagName('restrictions')
  if not restrictions_nodes:
      restrictions.append(0)
      continue

  result = []
  for restrictions_node in restrictions_nodes:
      restriction_nodes = restrictions_node.getElementsByTagName('restriction')
      for restriction_node in restriction_nodes:
          result.append(restriction_node.attributes['id'].value)

  restrictions.append(result)

print(restrictions)
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect and works awesomely, but can you please take a quick peek to my edit on the question? Thanks!!

Comment: @rodrigocf Do you mean if a topic doesn't have restrictions nodes, 0 should be inserted into the result list?

Comment: Exactly, for example, if we add third topic to the example above that has no `<restrictions>` the result should be `[['US','CA','EU'],['JP','AU','EU','US'],0]`